# Git and GitHub usage questions

Tags: git, github

I'm finding it hard to figure these out from the
Git references, so I have some Git/GitHub questions:

I'm learning more but I'm still pretty much a Git nube.

1. How can I get the project's main directory to appear
   in the GitHub master?  So that when someone downloads it
   they'll get the expected (sorry can't format it right):

   ```
   Main_Project_Dir
   File1
   File2
   ```

And not just all the files?
Would I have to do a git add like:

```
git add .   ??
```

I'd rather 'add' individual parts and somehow
add the outer directory, if that's even possible, as it's a lot harder to
do an "git add ." when I want to have better control
over what files and inner directories get added/tracked.

2. I have two different versions of a config.properties file,
   one has my passwords, and the other has generic passwords, which
   I want the GitHub master to have.

I want the GitHub master to only have the one with the generic passwords
and I don't want it to track the version that has the real passwords,
so how would I do that?

In my project directory, to keep them apart, I'd have something like:

```
config.properties
config.properties~
```

3. Do I have to add the [X] in:

   git remote add [X] https://github.com...

Some things say it just "names" the URL, but I don't want the
GitHub master to be affected by it possibly naming it [X] master.

I think I had a situation before where the GitHub master had a 'master'
and a second 'Something master', and I don't want that to happen.

Does it just "name" the URL or is it going to affect the GitHub master name?

If it's easier, just answer what you can, then somebody else can
possibly answer a different part..

Thanks!

Comment: 1) **actually** structure your content using folders, 2) add the one with the real passwords to .gitignore, but preferably move it completely out of the folder to ensure you never add it 3) you need to name a remote locally, the typical and default name is "origin" for where you cloned the repository from

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Lasse,

I think I found a solution to everything.

I did everything using GitHub Desktop, pointing to
a distribution directory of my project, which has it's own
generic password version of the config.properties, and it automatically "created" an outer XXX-master directory, which was fine.

Thanks!